# How to check if an agent arrived at certain point node?

Tags: anylogic

Hi Iam moving a truck to a point node along with a path using `main.trucks.get(0).moveTo(main.nodeHill);`  This works successfully and now I want to check if the truck is arrived to the point node. Is there any way to check that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you would use a statechart to move the agent. One of the transition types is "on agent arrival", which is triggered when the agent arrives.

So if you call `moveTo(main.nodeHill)` in your truck agent statechart's "on enter" code box, and if you have the only exit transition of type "on agent arrival", it will trigger when it arrives at `nodeHill`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you model logic (whether you are using state-charts or PML) you should have some "on enter" under "Actions" in the properties pane.

I suppose you select the block representing end of truck movement and insert the code:

```
traceln("Truck movement complete");
```

This message will pop up in the console if movement to the node was successful.